# ASP.NET WebParts and Google Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, performance, web-parts

**Hi there**

I started learning ASP.NET these days. Google Chrome is my default browser and I'm also testing my applications in Google Chrome.

I recognized that some Elements of ASP.NET won't run in real time when I use Chrome. For Example ASP.NET WebParts. If I change the modus of the WebPartManager from default to edit (or something else), Google Chrome needs 1 - 2 seconds to renew the page. Internet Explorer does this in real time without any loading times.

**Any tips to tweak this?**

*I'm a rookie in ASP.NET and many people said, Microsoft's AJAX for ASP.NET is some kind of crap.
I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and maybe you'll say, I should use jQuery instead of internal Features like WebParts.*

Comment: Update the asp.net ajax and get the latest version.

Comment: How I have to do that? Downloading Ajax Control Kit? http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got my answers over Twitter. People said, this just happens when asp.net applications runs over Visual Studio's Server.